# Meaning of some phrases in The Grapes of Wrath

Tags: meaning, john-steinbeck, the-grapes-of-wrath

I've started reading *The Grapes of Wrath* and I've run into some old-time phrases that I'm not sure of the meaning. I suppose these must date from the 1920s-1940s.

> My dogs was pooped out.

From context I take it to mean his feet are tired from walking, but I'm curious as to the origin of this phrase.

> He just done it for ducks

Does it mean he's doing it for show?

> He wasn't puttin' on no dog.

No idea.

Is anyone familiar with these? Were they actually real phrases, or turns of phrase invented by Steinbeck?

Comment: "Pooped (out)" and "putting on the dog" are real phrases. I don't know about "for ducks".

Comment: And *dogs* for *feet* is real slang — consider the shoe brand *Hush Puppies* whose motto was at one time (if I remember correctly) *they quiet your barking dogs.*

Comment: "For ducks" means just for fun.

Comment: @DavidAnson Do you have a source for that meaning of "for ducks", or just that it makes sense in context? Both bobble and I searched online for such a phrase and couldn't find any reference to it except in this same *The Grapes of Wrath* passage.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: I puzzled over this as well... unfortunately, I cannot offer additional insight on this expression... the best I could do was locate a couple of sites that offer idiomatic expressions regarding ducks... I looked in a three volume Webster's Dictionary which, likewise, was of no help here... but here are the idiom links:  https://englishbyday.com/duck-idioms/
http://fle135-idioms.pbworks.com/w/page/5905542/Idioms-with-Duck

Comment: @DavidAnson, those are actually some of the sources I found while searching to see if this was a real idiom. However I dismissed them (and many more) as no relevant idiom was to be found.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*(I'm doing these slightly out of order for reasons of convenience)*</sub>

> **My dogs was pooped out.**

"Dogs" was [slang for "feet"](https://www.familysearch.org/blog/en/spiffy-1920s-slang-words/), originally from [journalist T. A. Dorgan in 1913](https://books.google.com/books?id=Iz2CDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT153&lpg=PT153&dq=1913+T.+A.+Dorgan+dog+feet). "Pooped out" is [an idiom meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poop%20out) that someone/something is exhausted. Thus "My dogs was pooped out" is an informal way of saying "My feet are very tired".

> **He wasn't puttin' on no dog.**

"Put on the dog" is [an idiom meaning](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+the+dog) to to behave self-importantly/ostentatiously. Thus, "He wasn't puttin' on no dog" would mean "He wasn't acting self-important".

> **He just done it for ducks.**

This one is trickier. I found a [forum thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cause-he-just-done-it-for-ducks.3403912/) speculating on the same line, and they  weren't sure:

> From the context, it seems to mean that he just did it for a joke, or for fun. I can't recall having heard this expression before.

> I can't find any other instance of its use, but I suspect Barque [the previous poster] is correct. Note that "ducks" rhymes with "yucks," which is slang for laughs.

The context from the book:

> "Well, it makes you mad to hear a guy use big words. 'Course with a preacher it's all right because nobody would fool around with a preacher anyway. But this guy was funny. You didn't give a damn when he said a big word 'cause he just done it for ducks. He wasn't puttin' on no dog."

Or:

> "Well, it makes you upset when someone uses big, fancy words. Of course it's okay with a preacher, because no one would dare mess with a preacher anyways. But this guy was funny. You didn't care when he used big, fancy words because he <just done it for ducks>. He wasn't acting self-important."

So yes, it makes sense in context that "just done it for ducks" would mean "just did it for fun".

(The most relevant duck-related idiom I found was in another [forum post](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/54/messages/1016.html), which said that "just for ducks" meant "just for the hell of it" - but no one else knew it, and the post said it was from the 1970s which doesn't fit the timeline here.)

Answer (score 2):

Green's Dictionary of Slang gives three examples of "[for ducks](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/cbmc6ba#3qonmly)" before the Steinbeck one:

**1900** F.V. Fisher Transformation of Job 13: *‘Gracious sakes, boy! what did you scare me for?’ [...] ‘Oh, just for ducks!’.*

**1913** J. London Valley of the Moon (1914) 520: *I passed young Chavon [...] an’ – I don’t know why – just for ducks, I guess – I up an’ asked ’m if he thought the old man would lease the hundred an’ forty.* [US]

**1931** L. Steffens Autobiog. 276: *‘But what are you doing it for?’ ‘Oh, just for ducks.’* (context 1890s)

**1939** J. Steinbeck Grapes of Wrath (1951) 12: *He just done it for ducks. He wasn’t puttin’ on no dog.* [US]

**1962** E. Shepard Press Passes 219: *They’re never happier than when pounding newsmen with their rifle butts, just for the ducks of it.*

(Jonathan Lighter's Historical Dictionary of American Slang was Green's source for the 1931 and 1962 examples.)